# How to get Full Path Of Listbox Item

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I want to get Full Path Of Listbox item, because I want to showing all item of ImageListView , Can you give me some idea , If I add A Folder, All Items Of A will show in ImageList View Then it could save setting , Again I add B Folder , All Items Of B will show in ImageList View and save setting.

Thanks in Advance !!

```
        BindingSource listboxsource = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listboxsource = new BindingSource(Properties.Settings.Default.listboxitems, "");
            someListbox.DataSource = listboxsource;

        }

//Add Folder in Listbox
     private void button57_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            dialog.Description = "Please Select Folder";

            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string folderName = dialog.SelectedPath;

                string s = Path.GetFileName(folderName);
                listboxsource.Add(s);

                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                listboxsource = new BindingSource(Properties.Settings.Default.listboxitems, "");
                someListbox.DataSource = listboxsource;    
                }
                }
```

Comment: do you mean you want to show complete path of image file in list box ?

Comment: Yes I want add complete  path of image file in ImageListView :-

Comment: if (somelistbox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Listboxitem".ToString())
            {
                imageListView3.Items.Clear();
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"Get Full Path Of Listbox Items");
                if (Directory.Exists(dir.ToString()))
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
                    {
                        imageListView3.Items.Add(file.FullName);
                    }
                }
            }